# UICollectionView horizontal and vertical scrolling with Different cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm building an app where we can scroll vertically for 10+ section and for each section there is a horizontal scroll for 5 items.

There are several tutorial out there showing you, how to add collection view inside table view like this: https://johncodeos.com/how-to-add-uicollectionview-inside-uitableviewcell-using-swift/

I'm also following this approach.

**Table view > Table view cell > Collection view > collection view cell**

This works perfectly for a single collection view cell, and all the tutorials are using a single sized cell or most rarely 2 cell where they choose between cell-identifier based on the table view rows. But the problem is that I have different cells of different design & size (10 cells).

***Current approach I am using :*** Creates 10+ Table view cell with .class files having each individual collection views and its delegates and for each collection view there is a respective custom collection view cell designed which differ from each other in designs.

Is there any way to use the single Table view cell with a collection view and pass them the different Collection view cells or its respective identifiers? or is there any approach where  I don't have to create 10+ tableview cells with collection view

The app is build for devices running iOS 11 and above so I cannot implement Compositional collection view layout

I'm new to Swift please Explain in details, Thanks